# LINQ query does not "see" the values in array

Tags: linq

here is my query

```
        var traj_of_user_2=
        from num in trajectoryArray
        where num.ID_User == 2
        select num.ID_Traj;
```

when i run the program, an exception appears (see the image)

what's the problem is your opinion? a friend of me told me that since the array is "lazy" there are no istances

[image]

Comment: The problem is your `trajectoryArray` has a `null` in it.

Comment: nope, if in debug mode i leave the mouse pointer on trajectoryArray, it shows me my 20kk list of values..

Answer (score 1):

There is a `null` in the array, and `num.ID_User` is failing. You can filter out nulls like this:

```
var traj_of_user_2=
    from num in trajectoryArray
    where num != null &&
          num.ID_User == 2
    select num.ID_Traj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only get `ID_User` when `num != null`

```
    var traj_of_user_2=
        from num in trajectoryArray
        where (num != null && num.ID_User == 2)
        select num.ID_Traj;
```

Comment: ah thanx you... i realized i loaded the "small" db version, with just the first 200000 rows, and the user is always 0 :D